# How to replace a column in bash

Tags: bash, awk

i have a command that manipulates a particular column in a file.i want to overwrite the output to the same column in the same file.

```
awk -F' ' '{print $2}' test | awk -F. '{print substr($1,1,7)"."substr($2,1,6)}' |  xargs printf "%014.6f\n"
```

input:

```
a 1.1
b 1234567.123456
```

output:

```
a 0000001.100000
b 1234567.123456
```

Comment: input:
a 1.1
b 1234567.123456
c 12345678.1234567

output:
a 0000001.100000
b 1234567.123456
c 1234567.123456

Comment: Please format the input into the question with proper formatting

Comment: So what is not working here?